# PHP session cookie in iframe - how to get a session reliably?

Tags: php, iframe, session-cookies

It's about an ecommerce project, that is a white label solution and gets embedded into the clients' website as an iframe. Classic approach as in: browser request -> php -> apache -> browser.

The session starts with `SameSite: none` as well as `secure`. These settings are fine for Firefox and Chrome(-ium based) browsers at the moment. Safari on the other hand is dismissing the cookie as soon as "Prevent cross-site tracking" is activated - which unfortunately seems to be the default setting.

Right now the starting page is creating the session. After page load, I'll query a second script via AJAX to get the session name. If both strings are equal after the AJAX call, it's fine and the cookie has been placed.

There is no additional fuss, as of trackers or anything alike. Just the good ol' plain PHP session. I don't understand, why this could cause any problems to anyone to justify declining the cookie.

**Long story short**: what other options are left? A shop without session isn't fun. PHPSESSID as a GET parameter isn't fun, either. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Your problem is not with samesite/secure, but simply with the fact, that your cookie will be treated as a _3rd-party cookie_ in this situation - and those get blocked by default by some browsers, in other instances more strict individual configuration or privacy extensions installed by the user might block them as well.

Comment: Is there any alternative to bypass this, e.g. with user interaction or something like that? So it will get recognized as "i explicitly want this one"?

Comment: Well each and every individual user could add an exception in their browser/extension privacy settings, to specifically allow 3rd-party cookies for your domain … but that is not very convenient, and might even go over the heads of less tech-savvy folk.

Comment: You, as the developer, can’t do too much about this (if you could, then every provider of a “bad” tracker would do the same thing, and thereby making this protection measure completely useless.) One “workaround” from the olden days, was to redirect out of the iframe first, so that your domain is visited as “top level” domain, set a cookie from there (which would be 1st party then), and then redirect back to the other domain with the iframe. Not very convenient for users either, plus not sure if that would still work today.

Comment: I confirm that redirection does not work anymore